# LazyLoadingException appears when I try to get an object from ManyToOne relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here's my entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Answer implements Serializable {
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user")
    private CoreUsers user;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="person")
    private Person person;
     
}
```

the service:

```java
@Transactional
public class AnswerService {

    @Autowired
    private AnswerRepository repository;

    public List<Answer> getAnswers(Long id) {
        return repository.findByMessagesidOrderBySenddateDesc(id);
    }
}
```

the repo:

```java
@Repository
public interface AnswerRepository extends JpaRepository<Answer, Long> {
    
    List<Answer>  findByMessagesIdOrderBySenddateDesc(Long id);
}
```

the applicationContext.xml

```xml
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class"  value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
                <entry key="org.hibernate.cacheable" value="false" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="cccPersistenceUnit" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I load a collection of Answer (List) in the JSF bean through my service class. When I try to obtain a Person object from the collection — everything is okay, but when I try to obtain a User object from the collection — hibernate throws LazyInitializationException. What am I doing wrong?

Am I right, that hibernate tries to obtain the user object out of hibernate session?

Pls feel free to ask any addition information.

Thanks for any helps!

*before create the thread, I googled many times*

**UPD.**
I set the entities up to Eager loading, and noticed that my app tries to load unexist ID from user table. That was the problem :)

Comment: i guess by the time you access the child object, its detached from session so you are unable to access them.

Comment: Because after transaction is done, the session is closed, so you have detached object now which will not load lazy object, please check similar questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't mess around with the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` property when using Spring. Remove it as it breaks proper tx management in a spring application.

Comment: @krishnathota i read a lot of similar threads, and tries many of advices, but unfortunately no one works. 

Okay, I get that the child object is being obtained out of session. So what is might be a possible solution? Can I handle hibernate session manually or something?

Comment: @M.Deinum okay, removed it

Comment: try `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)`, in this case all the children objects fetch from DB along with the parent one. see if it can help you.

Comment: @krishnathota thanks buddy, it helps me a lot! Because of this I've been noticed that my app tries to load unexist id from user table!

Comment: happy to help you! @IhorSoroka

Answer (score 0):

You can get your complete objects tree with :

```java
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
public List<Answer> getAnswers(Long id) {
    return repository.findByMessagesidOrderBySenddateDesc(id);
}
```